# Reporting Services deployment with SharePoint

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to find out if it is better to deploy Reporting Services and Sharepoint Server on the same Server or not and what would the reason be for either case. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason that Reporting Services is not integrated with SharePoint is licensing restrictions. I am not a licensing expert, but I believe any server on which Reporting Services is installed must have a SQL Server license. Since SQL Server is usually installed on servers other than the SharePoint app servers, this involves extra SQL costs.

SharePoint and SSRS integration allows reports to be stored in a SharePoint library and provides an easier way to store report output (subscriptions) to SharePoint libraries.

Comment: Are there any resource constraints? Like SQL consuming too many resources?

Comment: For most use, SSRS uses a small fraction of the resources that either a SQL Server supporting SharePoint or a SharePoint application server will use. I'm sure you could build a report that would be resource intense on SSRS, but that would be very unusual.